# Keep windows time in a python clock while changing windows time.

Tags: python, windows, systemtime

I am looking for a way to basically create a clock to store the current windows time. The reason I need a separate clock is I am changing the windows system time using python. So I would like to set the windows clock back to what the time should be after a whole bunch of other java and batch files has executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using win32api then use [win32api.GetSystemTime](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__GetSystemTime_meth.html) and [win32api.SetSystemTime](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__SetSystemTime_meth.html):

```
system_time = win32api.GetSystemTime()
# do stuff here
import subprocess
filepath="D:/path/to/batch/myBatch.bat"
p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
#p.returncode is 0 if success
# more stuff
win32api.SetSystemTime(*system_time)
```

Comment: If I wanted  to call a batch file in the # do stuff here , how would I make python to wait for that batch file to finish and then adjust the system time to what it should be ?

Comment: check edited answer. Python will execute bat file synchronously so once bat is executed and finished, SetSystemTime will get executed